# Hibernate Mapping : Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have two classes Employee and Application. 
Employee has an employeeId(PK). Application has two fields employeeId(fk) managerId(fk). Both employeeId and managerId should refer to employeeId of class Employee. So i have following mappings in the respective hbm.xml files:

Employee.hbm.xml

```
   <hibernate-mapping package="com.quinnox.resignation2.0.model">
        <class name="Employee" table="Employee">
            <id name="employeeId" type="int">
                <generator class="native"></generator>
            </id> 
</class>
<hibernate-mapping>
```

Application.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.quinnox.resignation2.0.model">
    <class name="Application" table="Application">
        <id name="applicationId" type="int">
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="empId" class="Employee" column="employeeId" />
        <many-to-one name="managerId" class="Employee"
            column="employeeId" />
</class></hibernate-mapping>
```

I have also created appropriate POJOs. When I try to run the application i get the following error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.quinnox.resignation2.0.model.Application column: employeeId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

I cannot set insert="false" or update="false" and both the foreign keys should map to employeeId of Employee table. What do I do?

Comment: why your design needs two columns mapped to one foreign key, it would be better to have just one foreign key (name it appropriately though)

Comment: @SajanChandran No, i need to reference it to employeeId itself since manager himself is also an employee

Answer (score 0):

```
 <many-to-one name="managerId" class="Employee"
        column="employeeId" />
```

May be it should reference `managerId` column rather than `employeeId`

```
 <many-to-one name="managerId" class="Employee"
        column="managerId" />
```

Comment: No, i need to reference it to employeeId itself since manager himself is also an employee

Comment: Then just add to the insert="false" update="false" to <many-to-one name="managerId" ...>